# Changing contents of multiple divs depending on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have 5 sections on my site, and a fixed div with 2 divs inside that I want the contents to change depending what section is scrolled over/in view.

I found this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/6RHys/)  which is like what I want to achieve but not quite, and I can't work out how to make it work for me.

Here is the JS code used in that jsFiddle which I assuming a few modifications should be all it takes:

```
 $(window).load(function () {
     $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        var pos = $('#date').offset();
          $('.post').each(function () {
        if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top)        {
            $('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text()); //or any other way you want to get the date
            return; //break the loop
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
});

})
```

Here is a few snippets of HTML from my site:

The sections:

```
    <section id="space">
</section>
<section id="sky">
</section>
<section id="home">   
</section>
<section id="about">
</section>
<section id="involved">
</section>
```

And the 2 divs:

```
 <div id="caption1" class="nivo-html-caption">
     <h1><strong>Test Test Headline home</strong></h1><em></em>
       <div class="headline"><p>Home1 Home1 Home1</p></div>
 </div>

 <div id="caption2" class="nivo-html-caption">
     <h1><strong>Test Test Headline 2 home</strong></h1> <em></em>    
       <div class="headline"><p>Home2 Home2 Home2</p></div>
 </div>
```

So to summarise, when scrolling over the home section the text between the "h1" and "p" tags in the div "caption1" and the text between the "h1" and "p" tags in the div "caption2" will be unique to the "home" section but if for instance scrolling over the space section the text will change and be unique to the space section.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your summary is very confusing. Can you paraphrase this part?

Comment: Hi, I've edited it. Hope it's a bit clearer. Thanks.

Comment: It is but I can't see the difference between what you want and what is working in the Fiddle you've posted.

Comment: The only difference really is that I have 2 divs that I want to change. If I could get the JS from that Fiddle working with my the HTML I gave, I think that would do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the script of the fiddle, you will see this line:

```
$('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text());
```

Change it to:

```
$('#date').html($(this).find('.description').html());
```

This will clone the whole content you provide and not just the text in it.
Then you will need to provide a description in every section you have in HTML, and adapt the selectors in the script to your html structure, if needed.

In your case, you need to populate two divs, but this isn't really a big difference:

**JS:**

```
$('#caption1').html($(this).find('.description1').html());
$('#caption2').html($(this).find('.description2').html());
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="home">   
    content
    <div class="description1">content for caption1</div>
    <div class="description2">content for caption2</div>
</section>
```

**Don't use `<p>`-Elements as content holder. It won't work if they hold other HTML-elements. Just use a `<div>` instead.**

Here's an example: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontender/6RHys/9/)**</kbd>

Comment: I will give this a go. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to apply this to all sections with varying caption lengths if you use a single class name for all captions within a section a structure like

```
<section id="home">   
    content
    <div class="captions">
        <div class="nivo-html-caption">content for caption1</div>
        <div class="nivo-html-caption">content for caption2</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and then apply the content to the side container by

```
$('#side-panel').html($(this).find('.captions').html());
```